# SPSS Macro to create new variable based on 2 existing variables

Tags: macros, spss

I am trying to write a macro to perform the following operation:

```
do if SYSMIS(V2).
compute V3=V1.
ELSE.  
compute V3=V2.
end if.
```

I tried several approaches, but it always gets stuck on the compute command.

Comment: Code blocks should be indented by four spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. There's a preview for verifying that things look okay.

Comment: Your code runs perfectly fine on my computer. Can you specify your problem please? Did you get an unexpected result? Or did you actually mean you wanted to write a macro with the DEFINE command, but don't know how to do it?

Comment: @mirirai I want to write a macro to define a variable equal to all values of one existing variable (V2). If V2 is missing, I want the values of another existing variable (V1). I don't know how to do it. I have tried different things, but I get error messages. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post how your macro looks so far and what the error message is?

Comment: @mirirai Here is my syntax:
DEFINE crevar (VAR1=!CHAREND("/")/VAR2=!CMDEND).
!crevar V2/V1.
!IF SYSMIS(!VAR2) (!VAR1)=(!VAR3).
!ENDDEFINE.

Comment: @mirirai And the error message:
>Error # 6852 in column 5.  Text: SYSMIS
>In an !IF command, the parenthesized logical expression is missing.  !IF must
>be followed by a parenthesized logical expression and a !THEN command.
>Execution of this command stops.
!ENDDEFINE.

>Error # 6832.  Command name: DEFINE
>At the end of the macro definition, there was an unclosed structure, for
>example a !DO for which there was no matching !DOEND.  This problem could be
>the result of another error in the definition of the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing, you should know about SPSS macros is, that the SPSS macro language is just a "string parser". This means, the text within a DEFINE !ENDDEFINE block is parsed and as an output a syntax code will be created. The variables (beginning with "!") will be substituted by the strings(values) assigned to these variables.

So the line `COMPUTE !var1 = !var2.` will produce a compute command, with the variables names assigned to !var1 and !var2.

On the other hand a command like `!IF (SYSMIS(!Var2)) !Var1 = !Var3.`
makes no sense, because what you actually want is to execute an `IF` command, while `!IF` is a conditional macro directive, which 'decides' if some piece of syntax code be generated by the macro (if the condition is met), or not.

So you solution would look something like this:

```
DEFINE !crevar ( !POSITIONAL !TOKENS(1)
                 /!POSITIONAL !TOKENS(1)
                 /!POSITIONAL !TOKENS(1))
   DO IF SYSMIS(!2).
      compute !3=!1.
   ELSE.  
      compute !3=!2.
   END IF.
!ENDDEFINE.

* Macro call.
!crevar V1 V2 V3.

EXECUTE.
```

The macro call above, will be evaluated by the macro parser to the code you have given in your question.